# Wifi with CAS Authentication

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, authentication, wifi-configuration, central-authentication-service

I want to set up an access point for my student organisation providing to our members only network access, thus i would like to get them authenticated through our CAS System.

The hardware that i have right now available is :

- ZTE ZXV10 H108L
- BaudTec tw263r4-a2
- ZTE ZXHN H108L
- Computer available to run PfSense

and there is also the possibility to purchase a fairly cheap router if needed.

Answer (score -1):

CAS presently provides web-based interactive authN. (Or sometimes called passive authN). We'd have to know more about the access point's interface, and whether it's web based to tell you more.

There are also options for non-interactive authN. There is just not enough detail in this question to provide a meaningful response.

Comment: i already wrote what my hardware is, i don't have wireless interface for the pfsesnse, but i will select a compatible one if needed. The networking is kinda simple : the CAS server is over the internet other than the local network that will be served from the router / access point.